# PHP preg match to validate user text input

Tags: php, text, user-input, preg-match

I need to validate a user input of about 1,500 characters
Allowed characters are a-z A-Z 0-9
Allowed symbols . , : ? ! and space
Can anyone suggest a preg_match expression for this?
I am using '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,:?! ]+$/' but it gives error sometimes

Comment: That expression should work.  What error are you experiencing?  Do you have an example of input that should be accepted, but is not?

Comment: To get an answer to your question you really need to tell us what "error" you are getting.

Comment: I got my answer from Ish, basically I forgot to escape \ before signs... so the error was that the preg_match was not working as initially conceived. Thanks Ish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use escape \ before signs

/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\:\?\!]+$/'

Comment: Ish, thanks just one question, how should I add the space character to the preg_match? after the exclamation symbol?

Comment: Ish, can you check if this is correct I added \s for whitespace and carriage returns- [a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\:\?\!\s] thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,?!:\s]{1,1500}+$/i'
```

this one should work :))

Comment: `i` modifier here is not reuired.